# Audio output from applications goes to input (mic) in meeting

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 21.04

I spent several hours searching, but I cannot find the solution or the right keywords.

When I'm in the meeting (using microphone headset) attendees can hear the audio playing on my computer, eg. YouTube.

Now when the audio plays and I mute the microphone, attendees won't hear YouTube.

I tried several answers here and I could not find any solutions, this is really confusing.

Please let me know what other information you need.
These are my Alsa mixer settings:

[image: Alsa mixer settings]

Comment: I can tell you how to fix it if you'd like. If so, post the output of `pactl list sources` and `pactl list sinks`. Obviously, the bug will still be there, but it will not affect you. Be sure to tag me if you do, so I know that you've updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting with some friendly folks at #pulseaudio:matrix.org we found out it's most probably caused by the bug in Ubuntu kernel.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1930188