# Input audio gets computer sounds

Tags: sound, microphone

I don't know  nothing about sound drivers on linux.

After some recent updates my computer started to get all Output Audio  to my input audio device.

Clarification: All computer sounds (videos, voices, musics) are captured by the "input audio" I can hear it from my headset but i join any meting everybody can hear it too.

I tried 2 headsets and using the Computer audio, in all cases the output goes to the input audio.

As you can see on the image the input audio is capturing a music that is playing on my headphone.   OBS: on this case my mic is muted analogically.

I tried many solutions that I found around, but any of seems to work.
[image]

[$ pact list sources](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7Y45N8BNv5/)

[$ pact list short sources](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YS5R2Yhdgt/)

[$arecord -l](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NJkQxfktfy/)

[$ cat /etc/pulse/default.pa](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DsPp485tvP/)

---

Solution:

On alsa mixer the 1st tab represent the sound Output, I just had to set the "Headphone Mic" to zero.

[image]

Comment: your mic can not play audio (as far as I know). Can you clarify what "all Output Audio to my input audio device" means?

Comment: If I have any sound playing on my computer (output audio) and I join a meeting everyone else can hear it too. 
This is not my mic capturing the audio, is something happening directly on the audio config/settings. 

Sorry for the bad English, not my main language.

Comment: are you sure you don't have "share computer audio" or something like that selected in the meeting software?

Comment: Yes I am.  Even without being in a meeting if i go to settings I can se the  "bar" under "input device" going up  whenever I have any sound playing on my computer.

Comment: try using `pavucontrol` to ensure that nothing is set to "loopback" or "monitor"

Comment: also, hardware specs please? in [this case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356185/audio-output-from-applications-goes-to-input-mic-in-meeting) it was a driver bug. also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320217/mic-picks-up-all-system-sounds-including-game-sounds) are a bunch of other ideas to work on solving this

Comment: There is nothing set to loopback nor monitor.
I tested the second answere and there is nothing on record.  If I go to the "input device tabs" Both my "monitor"  and "built-in audio analog stereo" are getting the sound that are playing in the background (youtube).  

The 1st post dosen't seem the same error as mine. 
I'll be adding the hardware specs.

Comment: I was able to resolve it.  

For some reason the mic audio under Headphone Mic was being  enabled generating a loopback. Despite the name it was under "F3: Playback" and the PC audio was "being reproduced" as an output in the mic, generating the eco.